# How to add aurelia-animator-css to a cli-created project

Tags: aurelia

I created a new project using aurelia cli. I npm installed aurelia-animator-css and added `aurelia.use.plugin('aurelia-animator-css');` to main.js. However aurelia-animator-css never loads. What else do I need to do? I assume I have to edit aurelia.json, but I'm not sure what to add.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add this to one of your bundles' dependencies array:

```
{
    "name": "aurelia-animator-css",
    "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-animator-css/dist/amd",
    "main": "index"
}
```